# Ergodic for the mean, but not ergodic stochastic process?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes

Is there an example of a strictly stationary (zero mean, finite variance) stochastic process $(X_t\mid t\in \mathbb{N})$ that satisfies the conclusion of the ergodic theorem, i.e., the sample mean $\overline{X}_n\rightarrow_{a.s.} 0$, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, such that $X_s$ is uncorrelated with $X_t$, whenever $t\neq s$, but $(X_t\mid t\in \mathbb{N})$ is *not ergodic* (i.e., the underlying shift operator is not an ergodic transformation)? Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $Z$ be a random variable with $P(Z=1) =P(Z=2)=1/2$.

Let $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ be iid and independent of $Z$ with $P(Y_t = 1) = P(Y_t = -1) = 1/2$.

Set $X_t = Z Y_t$.  Then $X_t$ is stationary, and by the strong law of large numbers, $\overline{X}_n = Z \overline{Y}_n \to Z E[Y_t] = 0$ almost surely.  It is also uncorrelated, since for $s \ne t$ we have $$E[X_s X_t] = E[Z^2 Y_s Y_t] = E[Z^2] E[Y_s] E[Y_t] = 0 = E[X_s] E[X_t].$$
But $X_t$ is not ergodic; for example, the event $A = \{X_t = 2 \text{ i.o.}\}$ is shift invariant, but since $A = \{Z=2\}$ we have $P(A) = 1/2$.

Comment: excellent answer! many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the process $X_n = (-1)^n X_0$ where $X_0$ is a random variable with distribution symmetric about $0$ (but $|X|$ not a.s. constant).

Comment: thanks for your answer - I forgot one important piece of the problem: the process should be uncorrelated too. it's really just a pure curiosity that came up when I was reading stuff about stationary processes. any ideas for the modified problem? thanks!